# ARM Detect when an interrupt is taking too much CPU time

Tags: c, assembly, arm, interrupt, bare-metal

I have an interrupt in bare metal ARM C code, occuring several times per second, which needs to perform a lot of calculations.
I want to be able to detect if those calculations are taking too much cpu time (the current interrupt hasn't finished when the next occurs).

I've tried this sort of algorithm but it doesn't work :

```
bool isWorking=false;

void interrupt()
{
if(isWorking) errorCpuLoad();

isWorking = true;

... do the work...

isWorking = false;

}
```

Do you know why it doesn't work, and what better strategy I could use ? Is there a specific way of doing it in ARM C/assembly ?

EDIT : The Work load is user-configurable so the goal of this is to raise an alert when there is too much processing, instead of crashing or creating incorrect results. When the load is too high, the interrupt would return instead of processing things, so it can keep the rythm of interrupts without accumulating more and more delay

Comment: Don't perform a lot of calculations in the interrupt.

Comment: Define (in your question) what should happen when an interrupt comes again while handling of the previous interrupt is still running. Otherwise your question is unclear, since incomplete

Comment: Normally interrupts are locked out while in an interrupt routine, so the code ends up falling behind in responding to later interrupts. You could do something like a foreground / background "kernel", where the interrupt routine queues up requests for calculations, then exits to the queue handler, which does the calculations and then returns back to the main level code when the queue is emptied. This could also be done with a preemptive kernel. If you run out of the pool used for the queue, you need to speed up the calculations.

Comment: Clear an interrupt flag immediately. At the endow the routine, test it. If it is set, you are taking too long. But, as was said, don't do a lot of calculations in the ISR.

Comment: (what Eugene and user58697 said, and adding:) is that your actual C source? Then you need also to make `isWorking` atomic (old sources often abused `volatile`, which may be correct enough on some architectures) ... maybe check the interrupt disassembly to see if it was compiled as expected and the test is not optimized out somehow or reordered wrongly.

Comment: Does 'doing a lot of calculations' include calling a lot of 'C' or 'C++' library routines?  You maybe blowing up your stack or calling non-reentrant functions which fluke working.  Instead of what you have, can you grab a timer-tick to a local and then add a delta to a global at the end?  You should run a disassembler on the ISR when developing a routine to see what the compiler is generating.

Comment: Ratatax: have a look at Linux's top half / bottom half interrupt handler design.  I think it's similar to what @rcgldr described: the actual ISR that runs with further interrupts disabled is very light-weight, and just queues work for the bottom half.  The bottom half is scheduled like other tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The Work load is user-configurable so the goal of this is to raise an alert when there is too much processing, instead of crashing or creating incorrect results. When the load is too high, the interrupt would return instead of processing things, so it can keep the rythm of interrupts without accumulating more and more delay.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to measure the time between finishing the interrupt processing, and starting the subsequent interrupt. This means that rather than trying to detect the 'overload' condition, you can get a measure for how near to the limit you are.

If you have an idle thread, you can try to count progress there too (against a timer), which would mean that you avoid adding any overhead in the exception code. Here you would measure idle time only when there were spare cycles to do that measuring.